# Extract URL of a specific slide in a presentation with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides-api

I have an issue with Google Apps Script. I have a slide link of Google Slides in a Google Sheets file. I made a copy of both files and I want to update the slide link in the sheet with the new one. Could you help me to find a solution to do it? Because I didn't achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code you can accomplish your objective; that is to insert into the cell `B5` the URL of the third slide. You only need to insert into the code the required IDs and to activate [SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app) using `Resource ⮞ Advanced Google services ⮞ Slides ⮞ On`.

```js
function insertSlideURL() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    "{SPREADSHEET ID}").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var cell = "B5";
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(
    "{PRESENTATION ID}");
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  var slide = 3;
  var slideURL = presentation.getUrl() + "#slide=id." + slides[slide - 1]
    .getObjectId();
  sheet.getRange(cell).setValue(slideURL);
}
```

I hope that this fulfills your requirements. You can change the cell and slide variables to fit another cell/slide configuration.

For more clarification: I used [`getSlides()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation.html#getslides) to gather an array of every slide and [`getObjectId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide.html#getobjectid) to read its ID. Please, write me back if you need further help or more clarification.

Comment: Hi there @AntLas! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/589350) by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct the slide URL manually, using the Object ID from `Slide.getObjectID()`

Here is an example which will log the URL's for each slide in a presentation.

```
function getSlideURLS() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var base_url = presentation.getUrl();

  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  for(var i in slides){
    var slide_url = base_url+'#slide=id.'+slides[i].getObjectId();
    Logger.log(slide_url);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I believe it is ok but I would like to choose a specific slide for example in the cell "B5" in the google sheet I want to update the link of the slide number 3 when I make a copy of both files. With your code above it takes the link of the last slide.. I tried but it was a failure, do you have any ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is ok I achieved my objectif. Now I try to change the hyperlink by a name

Comment: This code was just an example of building the URL for all slides, I've updated the answer to mention that.

Comment: Thanks I accomplish my objective !

Comment: Is it possible to use the name rather than the slide number ?

Comment: I used this link in a Table of Contents inside a presentation and it opens a new copy of the presentation on the linked slide. To stay inside the existing instance omit the presentation URL. Just use '#slide=id.'+slides[i].getObjectId();